# Higher-Order Component accepts array?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I'm new to react and hocs pattern. What I wanted to do is joining components with `<hr/>` tag so that each component is separated by a line.
So I have:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

const withSeparator = (ComponentList) => () => (
  <Fragment>
    { ComponentList.reduce((prev, curr) =>
      <Fragment>{prev} <hr/> {curr}</Fragment>
    ) }
  </Fragment>
)

export default withSeparator;
```

And I'm wondering if this `withSeparator` is a HOCs because it does not accept Component but it accepts array of Components. And I'm wondering where should I put this `withSeparator` function, with normal utility functions or with the other hocs folder.

When I'm using it, it's kinda messy and break my project's style.

```
const Achievement = withSeparator(
  achievements.map((event, i) =>
    <React.Fragment key={i}>
      .
      .
      .
    </React.Fragment>
  )
)

export default <Achievement class="container" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you need `HOC` in this case. It might be done with a simple React component like below:

```
const Foo = () => <div>Foo</div>;
const Baz = () => <div>Baz</div>;

const ComponentListWithSeparator = ({list}) => (
  <div>
    {list.map((component, i) =>
      <React.Fragment key={i}>
        {React.createElement(component)}
        <hr/>
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
  </div>
)
```

Usage: `<ComponentListWithSeparator list={[Foo, Baz]}/>`

OR you may use `children` in this way:

```
const ComponentChildrentWithSeparator = ({children}) => {
  const childrenWithSeparator = React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => (
    <React.Fragment key={i}>
      {child}
      <hr/>
    </React.Fragment>
   ))
   return (
     <div>
       {childrenWithSeparator}
     </div>
   )
}
```

And then use it like:

```
 <ComponentChildrentWithSeparator>
    <Foo/>
    <Baz/>
  </ComponentChildrentWithSeparator>,
```

Both examples you may check [`here`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/95982/)